# How to update a UILabel in realtime when receiving Serial.print statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arduino

I am using a Bluno microcontroller to send / receive data from an iPhone, and everything is working as it should, but I would like to update the text of a UILabel with the real time data that is being printed from the `Serial.print(numTicks);` statement.  If I stop the flowmeter the UILabel gets updated with the most current value, but I would like to update this label in `realtime`.  I am not sure if this is a C / Arduino question or more of a iOS / Objective-C question.  The sketch I'm loading on my Bluno looks like the following, https://github.com/ipatch/KegCop/blob/master/KegCop-Bluno-sketch.c

And the method in question inside that sketch looks like the following,

```
// flowmeter stuff
bool getFlow4() {

    // call the countdown function for pouring beer


    // Serial.println(flowmeterPin);
    flowmeterPinState = digitalRead(flowmeterPin);
    // Serial.println(flowmeterPinStatePinState);
    volatile unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    // if the predefined interval has passed
    if (millis() - lastmillis >= 250) { // Update every 1/4 second
        // disconnect flow meter from interrupt
        detachInterrupt(0); // Disable interrupt when calculating

//        Serial.print("Ticks:");
        Serial.print(numTicks);
        // numTicks = 0; // Restart the counter.
        lastmillis = millis(); // Update lastmillis
        attachInterrupt(0, count, FALLING); // enable interrupt
    }
    if(numTicks >= 475 || valveClosed == 1) {
        close_valve();
        numTicks = 0; // Restart the counter.
        valveClosed = 0;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

On the iOS / Objective-C side of things I'm doing the following,

```
- (void)didReceiveData:(NSData *)data Device:(DFBlunoDevice *)dev {

    // setup label to update
    _ticks = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [_tickAmount setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ticks:%@",_ticks]];
    [_tickAmount setNeedsDisplay];
    NSLog(@"ticks = %@",_ticks);
}
```

Basically I would like to update the value of the UILabel while the flowmeter is working.

**UPDATE**

I just tested the functionality again with the serial monitor within the Arduino IDE, and I got the same if not similar results as to what I got via Xcode and the NSLog statements.  So this leads me to believe something in the sketch is preventing the label from updating in real time. :/  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does the `NSLog` display correctly at regular intervals?

Comment: @user3386109 No, last time I checked the flowmeter had to be stopped, will check again to make sure.

Comment: @user3386109 so I just checked again and when the flow meter is running NSLog totally seizes to print new data, but when I turn off the flowmeter NSLog continues reporting data.  Which is weird because the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE always updates with the latest data, so this leads me to believe it is problematic on the iOS side of things. :/

Comment: May be try to update the UILabel on the main thread. As i am not sure why it should not work. As i am not sure didReceiveData: is on main thread. Try using  performSelectorOnMainThread

Comment: @Sneha please see the update I amended to the question.

Comment: If you've concluded that the problem is on the arduino side, then I suggest starting a new question that has no mention of iOS or objective-C or UILabels. I think the people that can help you on the arduino side will be scared away by the question title, and the iOS stuff in the question. Also, you might want to give more information about the flow meter that you're using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817972/how-to-update-serial-print-statement-in-realtime-using-arduino