# How to update Serial.print statement in realtime using Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

I have the following sketch, https://github.com/ipatch/KegCop/blob/master/KegCop-Bluno-sketch.c that I'm running on Arduino UNO compatible microcontroller.  However I am trying to print statements while the flowmeter is in use with the following function,

```
// flowmeter stuff
bool getFlow4() {

    // call the countdown function for pouring beer


    // Serial.println(flowmeterPin);
    flowmeterPinState = digitalRead(flowmeterPin);
    // Serial.println(flowmeterPinStatePinState);
    volatile unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
    // if the predefined interval has passed
    if (millis() - lastmillis >= 250) { // Update every 1/4 second
        // disconnect flow meter from interrupt
        detachInterrupt(0); // Disable interrupt when calculating

//        Serial.print("Ticks:");
        Serial.print(numTicks);
        // numTicks = 0; // Restart the counter.
        lastmillis = millis(); // Update lastmillis
        attachInterrupt(0, count, FALLING); // enable interrupt
    }
    if(numTicks >= 475 || valveClosed == 1) {
        close_valve();
        numTicks = 0; // Restart the counter.
        valveClosed = 0;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, the `print` statements only get updated once the flowmeter has stopped operating.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.  As I would like the `print` statements to be updated while the flowmeter is in use.

Comment: What if you call `Serial.flush()` after `Serial.print(numTicks)` but before re-enabling the interrupt?  Also, you have two seconds of delaying in your `count` interrupt (which is usually a very bad idea, though I haven't made a connection to your question).  Didn't thoroughly review, but hope that helps.

Comment: @DavidDuncan calling `Serial.flush();` after the `Serial.print(numTicks);` yields the same results :/

Comment: You might get better help if you get a little more specific about what happens vs. what you'd like to see.  I would expect `Serial.print(numTicks)` to execute once per valve opening.  The while loop with `getFlow4()` is superfluous since `getFlow4()` always returns 0.  Once past that, `stringComplete` is cleared and so `getFlow4()` doesn't get to run again until a new command comes in.  Or that's what it looks like to me. :)

Comment: My other thought is that the [documentation for Serial.print](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) says the call returns before any characters are sent.  I'm not sure what the underlying implementation is, but it's possible if you tighten up your program flow and interrupts the issue will resolve itself.